# Правила преобразования цифровых url

Tags: url

Почему вот это http://1760468715 преобразуется в это http://104.238.158.235. Какое правило здесь используется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1760468715 (dec) == 68EE9EEB (hex) == 68.EE.9E.EB (hex) == 104.238.158.235 (IP)